# Reproduce R's summarise/reshape result in Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I want to reproduce behavior or R's `aggregate` function when using Python's `melt` function.

In R the data is as follows:

```
library("dplyr")

data <- summarise(group_by(table, project, resourcetype), 
                  count = n_distinct(resource_id))

  project resourcetype count
   <fctr>       <fctr> <int>
1 1000001            O     7
2 1000002            O     6
3 1000003            O    18
4 1000004            C     1
5 1000004            I     1
6 1000004            O    19
7 1000005            I     2
8 1000005            O    11
9 1000006            O     4

reshape(as.data.frame(data), 
        timevar = "resourcetype", 
        idvar = "project", 
        direction = "wide", 
        sep = "_")

  project count_O count_C count_I
1 1000001       7      NA      NA
2 1000002       6      NA      NA
3 1000003      18      NA      NA
4 1000004      19       1       1
7 1000005      11      NA       2
9 1000006       4      NA      NA
```

Now, in Python I get:

```
import pandas as pd

data = table.groupby(['project', 'resourcetype'], as_index=False)\
       .agg({'resource_id': {'count': 'nunique'}})

   project resourcetype resource_id
                              count
0  1000001            O           7
1  1000002            O           6
2  1000003            O          18
3  1000004            C           1
4  1000005            I           1
5  1000006            O          19
6  1000007            I           2
7  1000008            O          11
8  1000009            O           4
```

I have multiindex which I hoped to eliminate with `as_index=False`. I have `resource_id` and `count` in the last column and I'd like to have just `count` as in R.

I was trying to use `melt` function in Python but to no avail.

**Edit**: The original data is a table with 2000 rows and 19 columns.

**Edit2**: Concerning multiindex problem.

```
table.groupby(['project', 'resourcetype'])\
.agg({'resource_id': {'count': 'nunique'}}).reset_index()
   project resourcetype resource_id
                              count
0  1000001            O           7

table.groupby(['project', 'resourcetype'])\
.agg({'resource_id': {'count': 'nunique'}})
                     resource_id
                           count
project resourcetype                   
1000001 O                      7
```

What I'd like to get is:

```
   project resourcetype count
0  1000001            O     7
```

Comment: You are using `dplyr` lines which is not base R but another library. Please include all R library lines.

Answer (score 1):

Consider pandas' [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with update of column names:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE
text ="""
project resourcetype count
1000001            O     7
1000002            O     6
1000003            O    18
1000004            C     1
1000004            I     1
1000004            O    19
1000005            I     2
1000005            O    11
1000006            O     4
"""    
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(text), sep="\s+")

# PIVOTED DATA
pvtdf = df.pivot(index='project', columns='resourcetype', values='count')

# RENAME COLUMNS WITH RESET_INDEX
pvtdf.columns = ['count_'+str(i) for i in pvtdf.columns.values]
pvtdf = pvtdf.reset_index()

print(pvtdf)
#    project  count_C  count_I  count_O
# 0  1000001      NaN      NaN      7.0
# 1  1000002      NaN      NaN      6.0
# 2  1000003      NaN      NaN     18.0
# 3  1000004      1.0      1.0     19.0
# 4  1000005      NaN      2.0     11.0
# 5  1000006      NaN      NaN      4.0
```

Comment: Thank you, pivot does what I want. There is just one problem left - when I run `data = table.groupby(...).agg(...)` in Python I get multi-indexed df, so I don't have the same starting point as you do. `data.columns = MultiIndex(levels=[['resource_id', 'resourcetype', 'project'], ['count', '']], labels=[[2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]])`. Any idea how not to get multiindex or how to flatten it later? I tried `data.reset_index()` with no change.

Comment: Why are you doing the `groupby(...).agg(...)`? Isn't that an attempt to reproduce the R output? I am advising to replace this entirely for pivot. Or is this your input?

Comment: The original data is a 2000 x 19 table. I use `groupby(...).agg(...)` to first process it to just have 3 columns: `project`, `resourcetype`, and `count`. From that moment I like your `pivot()` solution. Of course, if you see an option to get from original table to final solution with just `pivot()` I'm all for it : )
For now I used simply `data.columns = ['project', 'resourcetype', 'count']` to flatten multi-index, but I'd love to have it that way straight after aggregating the table without writing names by hand.
I added information about original data to the original question.

Comment: When you tried `reset_index()` did you assign it back to data: `data = data.reset_index()`? Or you can chain it on `groupby`: `data = table.groupby(...).agg(...).reset_index()`.

Comment: I edited (#2) my question and pasted how dfs look like with and without `reset_index()`. I print the result to screen while testing.

Comment: In agg, why do you have nested dictionary? Try using just one, either *resource_id* or *count* as name to your `nunique` aggregate.

Comment: `transaction_table.groupby(['project', 'resourcetype']).agg({'resource_id': 'nunique'}).reset_index()` gives:
`project resourcetype  resource_id` which is wrong because the last name is name of the original column and not `count` which is expected name.
I also use dictionary of dictionaries in other longer aggregation when I work on multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution :)

```
import pandas
import rpy2
from rpy2 import robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

rdf = robjects.r('''
data <- summarise(group_by(table, project, resourcetype), 
                  count = n_distinct(resource_id))
data <- summarise(group_by(table, project, resourcetype), 
                  count = n_distinct(resource_id))
                  reshape(as.data.frame(data), 
        timevar = "resourcetype", 
        idvar = "project", 
        direction = "wide", 
        sep = "_")
        data[is.na(data)] <- NaN
        data
''')

pd_df = pandas2ri.ri2py_dataframe(rdf)
```

Comment: Well, to say the least, that's not the kind of solution I was looking for.

Comment: Why?  R syntax is much more natural for data munging (IMO).  There's no reason to switch, if you can integrate those features easily in python too.

Comment: I agree that R syntax is more user friendly. Unfortunately, I'm supposed to migrate the code from R to Python. I can't leave R running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reshape, we can also use `tidyr`'s `pivot_wider`:

```
r$> library(tidyr)
r$> library(dplyr)
r$> data = tribble( 
      ~project, ~resourcetype, ~count, 
      1000001,  "O",            7, 
      1000002,  "O",            6, 
      1000003,  "O",           18, 
      1000004,  "C",            1, 
      1000004,  "I",            1, 
      1000004,  "O",           19, 
      1000005,  "I",            2, 
      1000005,  "O",           11, 
      1000006,  "O",            4 
    ) 
r$> pivot_wider(
        data, 
        names_from=resourcetype, 
        values_from=count,
        names_glue="count_{.resourcetype}"
    )                                                                               
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  project count_O count_C count_I
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 1000001       7      NA      NA
2 1000002       6      NA      NA
3 1000003      18      NA      NA
4 1000004      19       1       1
5 1000005      11      NA       2
6 1000006       4      NA      NA
```

In python, you can replicate this using [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar):

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tribble, pivot_wider
>>> 
>>> df = tribble(
...     f.project, f.resourcetype, f.count,
...     1000001,   "O",            7,
...     1000002,   "O",            6,
...     1000003,   "O",            18,
...     1000004,   "C",            1,
...     1000004,   "I",            1,
...     1000004,   "O",            19,
...     1000005,   "I",            2,
...     1000005,   "O",            11,
...     1000006,   "O",            4,
... )
>>> df >> pivot_wider(
...     names_from=f.resourcetype,
...     names_glue="count_{resourcetype}",
...     values_from=f.count,
... )
   project   count_C   count_I   count_O
   <int64> <float64> <float64> <float64>
0  1000001       NaN       NaN       7.0
1  1000002       NaN       NaN       6.0
2  1000003       NaN       NaN      18.0
3  1000004       1.0       1.0      19.0
4  1000005       NaN       2.0      11.0
5  1000006       NaN       NaN       4.0
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of the [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package.